# How to do "inverse" substitution in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to find and substitute subexpression with a symbol, doing an "inverse" substitution of sorts.

Here is direct substitution example:
(`simplify` and `collect` added to make the resulting expression have the form that I need to work with)

```
In [1]: from sympy.abc import a, b, x, y, z
   ...: expr = (1 + b) * z + (1 + b) * y
   ...: z_expr = a / (1 + b) + x
   ...: subs_expr = expr.subs(z, z_expr).simplify().collect(1+b)
   ...: print(expr)
   ...: print(z_expr)
   ...: print(subs_expr)

y*(b + 1) + z*(b + 1)
a/(b + 1) + x
a + (b + 1)*(x + y)
```

Now I want to go back, and `subs` does not do anything:

```
In [2]: orig_expr = subs_expr.subs(z_expr, z)
   ...: print(orig_expr)

a + (b + 1)*(x + y)
```

How can I get back to `y*(b + 1) + z*(b + 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

The substitution attempt fails because subs_expr does not actually contain z_expr in its expression tree. "Substitute for an expression that isn't there" is not really a well-defined goal. A well-defined goal would be "eliminate a using the relation `z = z_expr`". That can be done as follows:

```
var('orig_expr')
orig_expr = solve([orig_expr - subs_expr, z - z_expr], [orig_expr, a])[orig_expr]
```

Now `orig_expr` is equal to `b*y + b*z + y + z`

Comment: Thanks! "Eliminating" is a really good term here. This works for this example, but I am not sure how to generalize this approach to a different problem of this kind. Why exactly do I need to solve for `a` in this example?

Comment: Because one needs to have a goal of substitution. "Find all occurrences of x and replace them with y" is one such goal, but that does not work when x is an expression that is not explicitly present in the formula. So an alternative is to say "use the relation x=y to eliminate something from the formula".

Comment: Ok, I probably oversimplified my example: both `a` and `x` are eliminated after substitution, which does not have to be the case. How could I apply same technique if my `subs_expr = a + x + (b + 1)*(a*y + x)`? I want to turn it into `(1 + b)*z + x + (1 + b)*a*y`. I will be happy to edit my question, if this more complicated expression can be simplified/solved. The goal is to bring in `z` using it's definition `z = z_expr`.

Comment: You can bring in `z` by adding `z-z_expr` to the expression. But then you'll probably say that it's not what you meant.  Unless you can clearly state the requirement that your desired expression satisfies (and others don't), you won't be able to explain it to the computer.